# Can we restrict websites access on AWS Workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, firewall, amazon-workspaces

I am trying to setup AWS Workspaces and all works fine. I also have a requirement to restrict certain websites like Google Drive, Dropbox, etc. on my AWS instance. How can I add these web access restrictions? Is it possible to configure and reply AWS firewall thru which these restrictions are applied?

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve that.

1. You can use some endpoint protection that allow web filtering e.g. Sophos, Trend Micro, ...
2. You can use a firewall appliance that allows to control the web traffic.
   https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results?x=0&y=0&searchTerms=firewall
3. You can use the new AWS Network Firewall to control the web traffic.

From: [AWS Network Firewall Features](https://aws.amazon.com/network-firewall/features/)

> AWS Network Firewall supports inbound and outbound web filtering for unencrypted web traffic. For encrypted web traffic, Server Name Indication (SNI) is used for blocking access to specific sites. SNI is an extension to Transport Layer Security (TLS) that remains unencrypted in the traffic flow and indicates the destination hostname a client is attempting to access over HTTPS. In addition, AWS Network Firewall can filter fully qualified domain names (FQDN).